# file.files[0] cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Oddly enough if I use this code in a jsfiddle it works perfectly

```js
var file = document.getElementById("file");
function CallAlert(){
 alert(file.files[0].name);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div>
   <label for="file">Choose file to upload</label>
   <input type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="CallAlert()">
 </div>
 <div>
   <button>Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

The result of this is an alert with the name of the file

Now on to my issue using this same method in sorts in my case this returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

```js
function _(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile() {
  var file = _('file1').files[0];
  if (typeof file === 'undefined') {
    _('status').innerHTML = 'ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button';
    _('progressBar').value = 0;
  } else {
    $.get('https://outsource.technologyforthefuture.org/wp-content/plugins/video-contest/shortcodes/handles/upload_handle.php?getsize', function(sizelimit) {
      if (sizelimit > file.size) {
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('file1', file);
        formdata.append('size', file.size);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener('load', completeHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener('error', errorHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener('abort', abortHandler, false);
        ajax.open('POST', 'https://outsource.technologyforthefuture.org/wp-content/plugins/video-contest/shortcodes/handles/upload_handle.php');
        ajax.send(formdata);
      } else {
        var sizewarn = 'ERROR: The File is too big! The maximum file size is ';
        sizewarn += sizelimit / (1024 * 1024);
        sizewarn += 'MB';
        _('status').innerHTML = sizewarn;
        _('progressBar').value = 0;

      }
    });
  }
}

function progressHandler(event) {
  // _('loaded_n_total_bytes').innerHTML = event.loaded+'bytes/''+event.total+'bytes';
  // _('loaded_n_total_kb').innerHTML = event.loaded/1024+'kb/''+event.total/1024+'kb';
  _('loaded_n_total_mb').innerHTML = Math.round(event.loaded / 1024 / 1024) + 'mb/' + Math.round(event.total / 1024 / 1024) + 'mb';
  var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  _('progressBar').value = Math.round(percent);
  _('percentage_loaded').innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + '%';
  if (Math.round(percent) == 100) {
    _('status').innerHTML = 'Generating Link Please Wait...';
  } else {
    _('status').innerHTML = 'uploading... please wait';
  }
}

function completeHandler(event) {
  _('status').innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
  _('progressBar').value = 0;
}

function errorHandler(event) {
  _('status').innerHTML = 'Upload Failed';
}

function abortHandler(event) {
  _('status').innerHTML = 'Upload Aborted';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="uploadFile()"><br>
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
  <p class="loading">
    <pt id="percentage_loaded"></pt>|
    <!--<pt id="loaded_n_total_bytes"></pt>|
         <pt id="loaded_n_total_kb"></pt>|-->
    <pt id="loaded_n_total_mb"></pt>|
    <pt id="status"></pt>
  </p>
</form>
```

What I am trying to do is when a file is selected it sends it as an ajax response to a script to put the file on our server. I dont see how this is producing an error when there is no difference in the example snippet vs my actual code other then the extra stuff around it but I dont see how that could be affecting it.

Perhaps someone smarter then me knows what the answer to this issue is.

Comment: What web browser are you using? It sounds like this may be part of it...

Comment: Chrome @ControlAltDel

Comment: @brk But the input has that id...

Comment: Why do you need underscore lib? What does `_('file1')` return

Comment: Try to log the input to see what it actually is:
`console.log(_('file1'));
var file = _('file1').files[0];`

Comment: Are you sure there are no other elements in the page with id `file1` right?

Comment: Seems to work as a snippet here, although ajax request fails because of CORS. `undefined` is not a string btw.

Comment: `console.log(_('file1'))`

Comment: @gbalduzzi is probably right, you might be having more than one `file1` element on the page. Consider upgrading your js-fu to using components ;)

Comment: I tried a console.log it did not popup the error came up but the log never did and I put it above the error line @KevinB

Comment: I changed the `id` and still the same error @jayarjo

Comment: Do not put `console.log(_('file1'))` anywhere, simply run it directly in the devtools console (on the page with the code from your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of this

```
function uploadFile() {
  var file = _('file1').files[0];
   ...
```

try this

```
function uploadFile(event){
 var file=event.target.files[0];
 ...
```

and don't forget to change this

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="(event)=>uploadFile(event)"><br>
```